# SSH/SCP using R from a windows machine

Tags: r, ssh, scp

I'm trying to write a R script (on a windows machine) that runs a remote shell command via SSH, then yanks a file using scp and manipulates it.

ssh.utils won't run on windows, RCurl keeps throwing "authentication failure":

```
 #Failed attempt:
    file <- scp(host = "1.2.3.4", path = "/path-to-file", key = "~/../Desktop/id_rsa.pub", user = "admin", keypasswd = "")
```

messages, even though I'm referencing it to the correct public rsa key.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: No idea until you post more details, especially your code.

Comment: You can run an appropriate client via `system`.

Comment: If you use rstudio, I think it should ship now with scp, see https://github.com/sckott/analogsea/issues/88

Comment: @arkascha - I've added the failed scp snippet. There's nothing else I can post since I haven't found other ways to implement this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
scp(host = "1.2.3.4", path = "/path-to-file", key = "~/../Desktop/id_rsa.pub", user = "admin", keypasswd = "")
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't work with R, but it's likely that you're using the wrong key file here. When you use a key file with an ssh client, you normally supply the private key file, not the public key file. In this case your private key file is probably named ".../id_rsa" without the ".pub" extension.